# Origem do significado de "mistura" - pt-BR

Tags: significado, etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica, regionalismo

Existe uma expressão que, acredito eu, é mais comum nos estados de São Paulo e Minas Gerais, apesar de já ter ouvido pessoas de outros estados a usarem também.

A expressão é **"mistura"**, e se refere à comida que é o acompanhamento do básico arroz e feijão. Pode ser aplicada sobre qualquer acompanhamento que venha com este prato.

Exemplo (partindo de pressuposto que o "prato base" do Brasil é arroz e feijão):

- Tenho um prato de arroz e feijão, com acompanhamento de salada de alface. A salada de alface, nesse caso, seria a **"mistura"**, pois não faz parte do prato base.
- Em outro caso, meu acompanhamento é bife com cebola. Bife com cebola é a minha **"mistura"**, pois não faz parte do prato base.

Espero que a ideia seja compreensível pois, apesar de ser um conceito que eu entenda facilmente, é difícil de colocá-lo em palavras.

**Minha pergunta é:**

De onde surgiu esse significado para a palavra **mistura**?

Comment: Fico pensando se não tem relação com as pessoas que recebiam sobras pra misturar na comida base. Supostamente disto surgiu a feijoada. A mistura também é aquela sobra que a gente dá pro porco.

Comment: Como não existe algum tipo de referência que remeta à essa origem, eu não tenho certeza absoluta sobre isso, mas penso a mesma coisa.

Comment: Não tinha ainda ouvido *mistura* para porcos. Normalmente aqui no Sul do Brasil, usamos *lavagem* para esses casos.

Comment: Verdade, Peixoto.  Estava tentando me lembrar qual era a palavra certa. Achei que fosse mistura mesmo, pois se aproxima da palavra lavagem. Mas bem lembrado.

Comment: Nunca ouvi "mistura" com esse significado no Rio de Janeiro.

Comment: Bem, é uma expressão mais regionalizada mesmo, normal não ter ouvido.

Comment: @Centaurus Então você também não conhece a expressão *"Isso é mais feio do que bater na mãe por causa de mistura"*? Eu achei que o termo fosse mais disseminado, mas pelo jeito é bem mais regionalizado do que pensei.

Comment: @Hugo, eu nunca ouvi.  As palavras e expressões em pt-BR que eu nunca ouvi geralmente caem em uma das seguintes categorias: ou trata-se de um regionalismo que exclui o Rio de Janeiro e que não costuma ser usado na mídia, ou é um socioleto, ou um idioleto, ou é arcaico, ou erudito demais, ou é usado muito raramente.

Comment: Esse uso de "mistura" também pode ser encontrado no norte do Paraná. Por exemplo "O que vai ter de mistura hoje?". Mas eu não usaria o termo para salada.

Comment: Sou nutricionista e qd lecionei não vi esse termo em nenhum lugar E já tenho quase 40 anos de formada
Só ouvi a pouco tempo e vim pesquisar

Answer (score 1):

No Guia dos Curiosos do UOL, a origem é da época da escravidão. Segundo o site, os escravos tinham acesso ao arroz e feijão, mas era restrito o acesso a proteína animal (nesse caso algum tipo de carne). Entendo assim, que o arroz e o feijão era o prato principal e o restante, considerado a mistura.
Segue abaixo a explicação do site:

> A palavra "mistura", usada como simbologia da alimentação, remonta aos
>   tempos da escravidão. Os escravos nas senzalas tinham acesso a arroz,
>   feijão e farinha, mas a proteína (carne, frango ou peixe), que sempre
>   foi cara, era dada em pequenas quantidades, para que fosse dividida
>   entre todos. Como sobrava um pequeno pedaço para cada um, a carne não
>   era encarada como um prato principal, mas como um complemento a ser
>   misturado no arroz e feijão. O hábito acabou caracterizando nossa
>   gastronomia (no prato típico brasileiro, há mais arroz e feijão do que
>   carne), e é por isso que usamos a palavra "mistura" para designar o
>   complemento proteico do prato.

Fonte: [Guia dos Curiosos - UOL](http://guiadoscuriosos.uol.com.br/categorias/5392/1/por-que-chamamos-a-carne-de-um-prato-de-mistura.html)